# How to pass data from method inside component1 to component2

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I got two components one console logs me indexes of carousel and I need to pass these indexes into second component.

**First Component**

```
<template>
  <div class="container container--white">
    <Header />
    <carousel-3d
      @after-slide-change="onAfterSlideChange"
      :width="250"
      :height="300"
      class="main__carousel"
    >
      <slide v-for="(img, i) in images" :key="i" :index="i">
        <img :src="img.src" />
      </slide>
    </carousel-3d>
    <CircleBottom v-bind:images="images" />
  </div>
</template>

export default {
.
.
.
  methods: {
    onAfterSlideChange(index) {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
      console.log(index);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

**Second Component - I need to place index into:**

> :src="articles[{{index}}].img"

```
<template>
  <div class="main__bottom-articles">
    <article class="articles__view">
      <div class="articles__view-top">
        <button @click="onCloseClick">-</button>
        <h1>{{articles[1].title}}</h1>
        <p>{{articles[1].desc}}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="articles__view-bottom">
        <img :src="articles[1].img" width="340px" height="auto" />
      </div>
    </article>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: What is the relationship between the 2 components? Second component is a child of the first?

Comment: No, 1st parent is component1 inside component1 is componentx and inside componentx is component2,

Comment: Are you using Vuex or another state management system?

Comment: Unfortunately no.

Comment: @mckvak You can not just pass the index down as a prop to componentx and then to component2?

Comment: @KonradSłotwiński Don't think so, that question refers to non-related components.

Comment: @MJ_Wales I started Vue yesterday, meybe yes, but I don't know how to. If u tell me how to store data from method inside component, its possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing data to child components is well documented here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html

In summary:

```
<parent>
  <componentx :index="index">
    <component2 :index="index" />
  </componentx>
</parent>
```

In the parent component all you need in the component is:

```
data: {
  index: 0
},
methods: {
   onAfterSlideChange(index) {
       this.index = index;
   }
}
```

And in componentx and component2:

```
props: ['index'],
```